# Customize LabelLayer extent based on density/location using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using a LabelLayer that can be seen only within a certain minScale - maxScale window. I'm trying to display labels of census tract IDs within Illinois, and the difference in label density between the Chicago area and the rest of the state is significant. Would there be a way to customize the minScale and maxScale settings based on the feature? I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'll just demonstrate what I'm looking for in pseudocode:

```
if ("County_nam" == "Cook") {
          minScale: 50000,
          maxScale: 0
    }
else if ("County_nam" == "Lake" or "County_nam" == "Dupage" or "County_nam" == "Will") {
          minScale: 100000,
          maxScale: 0
    }
else {
          minScale: 500000,
          maxScale: 0
    }
```